# How to get the instruction pointer in x86_64 without 0x00 or 0xFF bytes?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, shellcode, program-counter

Is there a way to access the value in the instruction pointer (RIP) without using a `call` followed by a `pop` in assembly language? Or is there a machine code opcode that can do it?

I have been googling with no clear results.

My problem is that I can't have any zeroes in the machine code, or else I get a SIGSEGV error. It's due to the way the server loads the code and executes it from a string of bytes. A near call has zeroes in the distance to the subroutine, so using call is not an option.

I'm on linux, 64-bit, and have nasm and yasm.

Comment: I also cannot have any 0xff bytes, so calling a subroutine above won't settle the issue.

Comment: Looking at the Intel docs for `mov` I see: *The MOV instruction cannot be used to load the CS register. Attempting to do so results in an invalid opcode exception (#UD). To load the CS register, use the far JMP, CALL, or RET instruction.*

Comment: You can use LEA to get the address of RIP. Syntax depends on assembler `lea rax, [rip+0x00]` may work. In NASM you can use `lea rax, [rel $+7]` (which will get RIP relative to the next instruction after the LEA).Unfortunately both will result in 0x00 or 0xff bytes. I'll assume this is a shellcode exploit you are writing?

Comment: how about `lea rax, [rip + 0x01020304]; sub rax, 0x01020304`?

Comment: @phuclv: yeah that'll work for shellcode, great idea to get *some* known address and then use other instructions to fix it up.  You should post that as an answer (including disassembly so we can see the opcode / modrm bytes.)

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Avoiding 0xFF bytes in shellcode using CALL to read RIP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/55778839) where I re-invented @phuclv's idea.  (I didn't consciously remember it, but probably having seen it on this question helped me "invent" it again.)  My version uses a label so you directly get the address of some nearby data into a register, instead of just the end of a RIP-relative LEA.

Answer (score 6):

In x86_64 the standard way is to use RIP-relative addressing instead of `CALL` like in x86. Even then, call/pop is not a recommended way<sup>1</sup>

Normally you'll use `lea rax, [rip]` to get RIP into RAX (which is actually encoded as `lea rax, [rip + 0]` with four bytes for the immediate at the end). However since `LEA` doesn't dereference the memory address, you can just add any constant displacements to the RIP and subtract it later

```
0:  48 8d 05 04 03 02 01    lea    rax,[rip+0x1020304]
7:  48 2d 04 03 02 01       sub    rax,0x1020304
```

You can choose any immediate values that don't have a zero or 0xFF byte. If you want the address of the instruction after `lea` (which is 7 bytes long) you can fix up accordingly with `sub rax, 0x01020304 - 7`

---

<sup>1</sup>[The recommended way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/16/317157.aspx) is

```
GetCurrentAddress:
    mov eax, [esp]
    ret
...
    call GetCurrentAddress
    mov [currentInstruction], eax
```

in order to avoid mismatching between the call stack and the return stack buffer (RSB). But probably it isn't important in shellcode

Comment: Turns out `call +0` is a special case, and doesn't break the RSB, and we've been worried over nothing.  Henry actually tested it: http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2018/04/ras-microbenchmarks/.  `call +0` / `pop` is fine on (nearly) everything.  But still use RIP-relative LEA in 64-bit mode, of course.

Comment: RIP-relative addressing is relative to the *end* of the instruction (like relative jump offsets), so your code block already gives you the address of the `sub`.  If you want the end of *that*, `sub rax, 0x01020304 - 6`.  (You can get the `6` from `label2-label1`, so changing `rax` to any other register will recalculate the offset when the special no-ModR/M opcode isn't usable.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Wow! I didn't know that.  I have to keep that in mind.